# Get rid of the sequence No. on the first column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Here I want to get rid of the series number on the first capital of the each line. How do I do in this file?

```
     1  #
     2  # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
     3  # OpenWrt Configuration
     4  #
     5  CONFIG_MODULES=y
     6  CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
     7  CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi=y
     8  # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1-Plus is not set
     9  CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1=y
    10  # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-R1 is not set
    11  CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD="sunxi"
    12  CONFIG_TARGET_ARCH_PACKAGES="sunxi"
    13  CONFIG_DEFAULT_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="-Os -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
    14  CONFIG_CPU_TYPE="cortex-a8+vfpv3"
    15  CONFIG_LINUX_3_18=y
    16  CONFIG_DEFAULT_base-files=y
    17  CONFIG_DEFAULT_busybox=y
    18  CONFIG_DEFAULT_dnsmasq=y
    19  CONFIG_DEFAULT_dropbear=y
    20  CONFIG_DEFAULT_firewall=y
    21  CONFIG_DEFAULT_fstools=y
    22  CONFIG_DEFAULT_ip6tables=y
^^^^  ^^
```

I am sorry. I should add the spaces before of the sequence of No. and mark them. There are spaces on the each row. Actually, there are over 4000 rows I have to handle. Here I just post 1-22. The command sed should work. I forget to explain explicitly. The regex is new and complex for me. Wish you give me an advice.

Comment: You want to remove line numbers, or the letter `C`?

Comment: I want to get rid of the number on each row. There are 1 to 22 that I want to remove them. I am sorry to brother you. Anyway, thanks. Thanks George. But, I used sed this command it is not ok. It still seems as before. It is nothing changed. I remember sed is for row. In this case, it might be awk to handle it. However, I am not sure how to replace the first column(field).

Comment: you should edit your title to make that clear

Comment: I amend the articles. Wish your kind advice. Thanks.

Comment: voted to reopen. In the meantime, try `'s/^ *[0-9]* *//'` as the expression for sed.

Comment: Do you want keep the spaces __before__ and __after__ the line numbers to remain?

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing whether your after `C` or the `line numbers` I offer these solutions:

1. To get rid of the `line numbers` use:

   ```
   sed 's/^ *.[0-9]  //g' line.txt

   # Result

   #
   # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
   # OpenWrt Configuration
   #
   CONFIG_MODULES=y
   CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
   CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi=y
   # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1-Plus is not set
   CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1=y
   # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-R1 is not set
   CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD="sunxi"
   CONFIG_TARGET_ARCH_PACKAGES="sunxi"
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="-Os -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
   CONFIG_CPU_TYPE="cortex-a8+vfpv3"
   CONFIG_LINUX_3_18=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_base-files=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_busybox=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_dnsmasq=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_dropbear=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_firewall=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_fstools=y
   CONFIG_DEFAULT_ip6tables=y
   ```
2. To get rid of the `C` use:

   ```
   sed '5,22s/ [C]//g' line.txt


   # Results

   1  #
   2  # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
   3  # OpenWrt Configuration
   4  #
   5 ONFIG_MODULES=y
   6 ONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
   7 ONFIG_TARGET_sunxi=y
   8  #ONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1-Plus is not set
   9 ONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1=y
   10  #ONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-R1 is not set
   11 ONFIG_TARGET_BOARD="sunxi"
   12 ONFIG_TARGET_ARCH_PACKAGES="sunxi"
   13 ONFIG_DEFAULT_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="-Os -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
   14 ONFIG_CPU_TYPE="cortex-a8+vfpv3"
   15 ONFIG_LINUX_3_18=y
   16 ONFIG_DEFAULT_base-files=y
   17 ONFIG_DEFAULT_busybox=y
   18 ONFIG_DEFAULT_dnsmasq=y
   19 ONFIG_DEFAULT_dropbear=y
   20 ONFIG_DEFAULT_firewall=y
   21 ONFIG_DEFAULT_fstools=y
   22 ONFIG_DEFAULT_ip6tables=y
   ```
3. To write to original file and create a *backup* use the `--in-place` option in `sed`command:

   ```
   sed --in-place=.bak '5,22s/ [C]//g' line.txt

   sed --in-place=.bak 's/^ *.[0-9]  //g' line.txt
   ```
4. To write to a new file:

   ```
   sed 's/^ *.[0-9]  //g' line.txt >> new_file.txt

   sed '5,22s/ [C]//g' line.txt  >> new_file.txt
   ```
5. To keep the spaces before each line:

   ```
   sed 's/^ *.[0-9]  /     /g' line.txt
   ```

Comment: Thanks!! But, I want to get rid of number.

Comment: In that case number `1` option should be what you want, let me know if that is the case so I can _vote_ to _reopen_ the OP...

Comment: Please give an example from the text you supplied, but I am guessing the first option should be the one...

Comment: Sorry. I modify the article. I am newbie on regex. Do you know how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}' ur4000rowfile.txt
```

will give:

```
#      
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# OpenWrt Configuration    
#      
CONFIG_MODULES=y      
CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y      
CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi=y      
# CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1-Plus is not set  
CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1=y      
# CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-R1 is not set  
CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD="sunxi"      
CONFIG_TARGET_ARCH_PACKAGES="sunxi"      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="-Os -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"  
CONFIG_CPU_TYPE="cortex-a8+vfpv3"      
CONFIG_LINUX_3_18=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_base-files=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_busybox=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_dnsmasq=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_dropbear=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_firewall=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_fstools=y      
CONFIG_DEFAULT_ip6tables=y
```

Or if you do this:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}' ur4000rowfile.txt
```

You will get the output like this:

```
 #
 # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
 # OpenWrt Configuration
 #
 CONFIG_MODULES=y
 CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
 CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi=y
 # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1-Plus is not set
 CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-M1=y
 # CONFIG_TARGET_sunxi_BPI-R1 is not set
 CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD="sunxi"
 CONFIG_TARGET_ARCH_PACKAGES="sunxi"
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION="-Os -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
 CONFIG_CPU_TYPE="cortex-a8+vfpv3"
 CONFIG_LINUX_3_18=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_base-files=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_busybox=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_dnsmasq=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_dropbear=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_firewall=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_fstools=y
 CONFIG_DEFAULT_ip6tables=y
```

---

Finally, if you wan't to use the output to create a new file, simply redirect the output to a new file like this:

```
awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}' ur400rowfile.txt > urnewcleanfile.txt
```

or this:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}' ur400rowfile.txt > urnewcleanfile.txt
```